# Spark - Scala calculation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to calculate using spark and scala the h-ndex for a researcher (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) from a csv file with data in the format

R1:B, R1:A, R1:B, R2:C, R2:B, R2:A, R1:D, R1:B, R1:D, R2:B, R1:A, R1:B

The h-index is the academic indicator of a researcher and it is computed by creating a sinlge list for all reacerchers with their publications sorted 
e.g R1 : { A:10 , B:5 , C:1} and then finding the index of the the last position where a value is bigger than itsindex (here is position 2 because 1 < 3).

I cannot find a solution for spark using scala. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I only know that it would a combination a flatMaps, Maps and ReduceByKey but I cannot go any further

Comment: You'd at least show how you read the data in. And what is the current data structure, is it a rdd or dataframe? The csv file you are showing doesn't look normal to me.

Comment: Each data in the csv file has a researcher id (R1,R2..) concatanated with a paper id (A,B,..) with : between. To read the data I use something like this
https://codepaste.net/4ugc87 where I pass the file name when I invoke the program.

The first step is a think to create a list with each researchers papers and their citations sorted e.g {R1 , List(<A,5>,<B,3>,..) } but I am stuck

Comment: Where does the blank space come from, shouldn't it be comma? Also how does `lines.take(5)` looks like? It would be great if you can update your question with the most recent results you get.

Comment: You are right there are blanks between the data  but lets assume that they don't exist. Lets say there are no blanks and there are all concatanated R1:A,R2:B,R1:C.... 
I still cannot advance much further than splitting each data part.
I think I need to create something like  {R1 , List(<A,5>,<B,3>,..) } for each researcher but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have a file like this:

```
R1:B, R1:A, R1:B, R2:C, R2:B, R2:A, R1:D, R1:B, R1:D, R2:B, R1:A, R1:B
R1:B, R1:A, R1:B, R2:C, R2:B, R2:A, R1:D, R1:B, R1:D, R2:B, R1:A, R1:B
R1:B, R1:A, R1:B, R2:C, R2:B, R2:A, R1:D, R1:B, R1:D, R2:B, R1:A, R1:B
```

Here are some thoughts:

```
// add a count field to each researcher:paper pair
input.flatMap(line => line.split(", ").map(_ -> 1)).
      // count with research:paper as the key
      reduceByKey(_+_).map{ case (ra, count) => {
          // split research:paper
          val Array(author, article) = ra.split(":")
          // map so that the researcher will be new key
          author -> (article, count)
     // group result by the researcher
     }}.groupByKey.collect

// res15: Array[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])] = Array((R2,CompactBuffer((B,6), (A,3), (C,3))), (R1,CompactBuffer((A,6), (B,12), (D,6))))
```

Comment: Thanks vey much. This is pretty close to what I wanted to do. If I wanted to have the array sorted by count number how would I do it?

Comment: You can use `mapValues` with `sortBy`, chain this `.mapValues(_.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2))` after `groupByKey` will sort the result by count in descending order.